# laravel subquery whereIn and maximum value

Tags: mysql, laravel

i'm newbie to laravel and mysql

mysql query is

`select * from table where id in ( select max(id) from table group by thread_id)`

my table is

```
id  thread_id
1    45a7
2    123c
3    45a7
4    d056
5    123c
```

output for mysql table is

```
id   thread_id
3    45a7
5    123c
4    d056
```

Here i tried to transfer my mysql query to laravel as below

`MODEL::whereIn('id', function($query){ $query->groupBy('thread_id')})->get();`

what's i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below should match your query

```
Model::whereIn('id', function($query) { 
    $query->selectRaw('max(id)')->from('table')->groupBy('thread_id'); 
})->toSql();
```

this will output

```
select * from "table" where "id" in (select max(id) from table group by "thread_id")
```